# Able to override the root permission of a readonly file in `Docker` with a non-sudo user

Tags: linux, files, permissions, vim, docker

I was performing some experiments in [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and found a strange behaviour.

I was able to override the ownership of a file created with the root
user inside the Docker with another user without root permissions.

Below are the steps to reproduce it:

```
$> docker run -dit ubuntu:16.04 bash
$> docker exec -it cont_id bash
$> apt update && apt install -y vim
$> useradd cp -m
$> vim /home/cp/hello.txt
  #  Write some text and save it

$> su cp 
$> cd ~/ && ls -latr;
  #  Will list hello.txt with user and group as root

$> vim hello.txt
  #  Write some text and try saving it normally which will fail.
  #  Try saving it with `:wq!`
```

Voila, it is saved and the user and group to which the file belongs also change to the new user.

I have done a terminal recording for this and the same is posted [here](https://asciinema.org/a/HhS1zIShEMs6lD0JPiyRKTGJl).

Comment: Possible dup of [How does vim steal root owned files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/how-does-vim-steal-root-owned-files)

Comment: And so it seems that the file is replaced with a new one. On performing `echo "sometext " >> /filePath`, doesn't change the inode value. Vim does change the inode value every time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this has nothing to do with the `Docker`. This is normal behaviour in `vim` where it will replace the file with a new one as the user, given, the user has full permission on a folder. The same cannot happen for a folder where the user doesn't have full permission.