# User is able to edit a file using vim

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, vim

I have a file named `file.txt` with some contents located in `/home/myuser` directory and I change the permissions of that file to `root.root` and `644`.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K Jan 15 07:09 file.txt
```

Then I switched to `myuser` and opened it with `vim`(**without sudo**) and tried to edit and save it `:wq!` and I got output like:

```
"file.txt" E949: File changed while writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Then I hit enter and then again `:wq!` and the output was :

```
WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!
Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?
```

I hit `y`, the file got saved and exit from `vim`.

The question is why a file with `ROOT` privileges and `read-only` access for a user changed by the way?

PS: 1. `myuser` is a sudo user.

2. The user permissions after saving the file changed to `myuser.myuser` as well.

   `-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.4K Jun 27 18:57 file.txt`

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory where the file lives? If the user has write access to it, they are able to delete the file and recreate it.

Comment: It is the home directory of `myuser`. So what is happening is deleting and recreating? PS: The user permissions after saving the file changed to `myuser.myuser` as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular user is able to modify a file owned by root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761598/regular-user-is-able-to-modify-a-file-owned-by-root)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does vim steal root owned files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/how-does-vim-steal-root-owned-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file lives in a directory that is writable by the user, the user has permissions to delete and recreate the file.  This is more or less what `vim` does when you force write to the file.

```
$ ls -li file
3481899 -r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  6 Jun 27 15:48 file

$ vim file

$ ls -li file
3481905 -rw-r--r--  1 myself  myself  6 Jun 27 15:49 file
```

As you can see in this example, the file has been recreated and has a new inode number.  The user and group has been set to the user who wrote the file, and the permissions have been set according to the user's `umask`.